# process got suspened with using restic with fzf

Tags: zsh, fzf

in zsh, when I try to filter the results of `restic ls` with `fzf`, the process automatically put to background with "suspended (tty output)". eg.

`restic ls -q <repo_id> /some/path | fzf`

How can I keep the process in foreground?

Comment: Which process goes to the background - restic or fzf?  I don't know either of these commands, but if they are not supposed to detach themselves, I would first check whether you have a command of the same name, which shadows the real ones. I.e. do a `type -a restic`, respectively `type -a fzf`.